# use @value in non-bean class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, singleton, spring-ioc

I am working on spring boot project.I create a singleton class in my spring boot application.I wanna get properties from application.properties in my singleton class.is it possible in non-bean class?How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Spring bean is [singleton scope by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes). Therefore you should not use Java singleton class pattern in Spring driven application, just use spring bean and inject `@Value` there.

Comment: thanks man!But i finally found the pattern to do it in spring!